# Accessing Windows 10 Notifications fails

Tags: c#, push-notification, uwp, windows-10, toast

I have been following these steps to build an app that intercepts Windows 10 notifications and adds them to an ItemsControl following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener#requesting-access-to-the-listener

The app does not work. I am at a loss on how to write unit tests for such an app or how to test or debug it. Any pointers on it will be greatly appreciated.

Update: Based on Andrew's comment I installed Notification Visualizer and popped notifications. My app captures them and handles them as designed. However the problem remains that push notifications from outside websites such as Facebook are not handled by the app. It appears to me that browsers utilize their own notification mechanism separate from Windows's. Is there a way to intercept Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge's notifications?

The app has the following XAML and three code pages:

Mainpage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,150,0">
        <Button Content="Run Listener" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.492,0.049" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ItemsControl Name="NotificationsIC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="376" Margin="25,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="775"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

App.xml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
            {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                    // parameter
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
                }
                // Ensure the current window is active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }

        protected override async void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var deferral = args.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();

            switch (args.TaskInstance.Task.Name)
            {
                case "UserNotificationChanged":
                    // Call your own method to process the new/removed notifications
                    // The next section of documentation discusses this code
                    await NotifcationsProcessor.SyncNotifications();
                    break;
            }

            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;
using Windows.UI.Notifications.Management;
using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public static UserNotificationListener listener = UserNotificationListener.Current;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            NotificationsIC.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
            SpeechSynthesizer synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

            await IsListenerSupported(mediaElement, synth);

            // Get the listener

            UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus accessStatus = 
                await listener.RequestAccessAsync();
            if(accessStatus != UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Allowed)
            {
                await SaySomething(mediaElement, synth, "Access to notifications was not allowed. I can not do anything more. Exiting. Sorry.");
                return;
            }

            // Get the toast notifications
            NotifcationsProcessor.GetNotificationsAndProcessThem();
            //Request / check background task access via BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync
            var requestStatus =
                await Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            if (requestStatus != BackgroundAccessStatus.AlwaysAllowed)
            { //AllowedSubjectToSystemPolicy is ok too see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundaccessstatus
              // user has to give permission in the battery use settings:
              //On devices that have a battery, the user has given the app permission in the battery use settings to always allow background access. Introduced in Windows 10, version 1607.


              // Depending on the value of requestStatus, provide an appropriate response
              // such as notifying the user which functionality won't work as expected
            }


            // If background task isn't registered yet
            if (!BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.
                   Any(i => i.Value.Name.Equals("UserNotificationChanged")))
            {
                // Specify the background task
                var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder()
                {
                    Name = "UserNotificationChanged"
                };

                // Set the trigger for Listener, listening to Toast Notifications
                builder.SetTrigger(new UserNotificationChangedTrigger(NotificationKinds.Toast));

                // Register the task
                builder.Register();
            }           
        }

        private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task 
            IsListenerSupported(MediaElement mediaElement, SpeechSynthesizer synth)
        {
            string ListenerIsSupported;
            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener"))
            {
                ListenerIsSupported = "Listener Is Supported";
            }
            else
            {
                ListenerIsSupported = "Oh no!  Listener Is NOT Supported. Oh No!. You need to upgrade your windows to the latest version of Windows 10.";
            }
            await SaySomething(mediaElement, synth, ListenerIsSupported);
        }

        private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SaySomething(MediaElement mediaElement, SpeechSynthesizer synth, string WhatToSay)
        {
            Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisStream stream =
                await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(WhatToSay);
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

NotificationsProcessor.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Windows.UI.Notifications.Management;

namespace App1
{
    public class NotifcationsProcessor
    {
        internal static async Task SyncNotifications()
        {
            NotifcationsProcessor.GetNotificationsAndProcessThem();
        }

        public static async void GetNotificationsAndProcessThem()
        {
            IReadOnlyList<UserNotification> notifs =
                 await MainPage.listener.GetNotificationsAsync(NotificationKinds.Toast);
            foreach (var n in notifs)
            {
                // Get the toast binding, if present
                NotificationBinding toastBinding = n.Notification.Visual.GetBinding(KnownNotificationBindings.ToastGeneric);

                if (toastBinding != null)
                {
                    // And then get the text elements from the toast binding
                    IReadOnlyList<AdaptiveNotificationText> textElements = toastBinding.GetTextElements();
                    string bodyText =
                       string.Join(" | ", textElements.Select(t => t.Text));
                    MainPage.items.Add(bodyText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I have ran this in the debugger with plenty of breakpoints hoping that when a notification comes through, a breakpoint will be hit. No such luck. I also side loaded the app on my development machine and still got no sign that it was intercepting the notifications.

Comment: I tried out your exact code, deployed the app with debugging, set a break point in OnBackgroundActivated, and then popped a toast using Notifications Visualizer and OnBackgroundActivated was called. You verified that a breakpoint on registering the background task gets called? What OS version are you running? Version 1607?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I didn't know about Notifications Visualizer. When I popa toast my app works as expected. The issue is that regular push notifications that are coming in from outside sources are not triggering my app. I guess there must be a difference between them and the toast notifications here. I appreciate it if you can shed a light on the difference and how I might be able to capture those also.  I am running version 1709, OS build 16299.192.

Comment: To clarify, I want to capture the notifications that websites such as Facebook send to the PC.

Comment: Ah, those notifications are not toast notifications. I believe you're talking about the notifications Chrome shows? Those are custom UI drawn by Win32 apps. They are not using the Windows 10 notification framework, so our notification platform has no knowledge of them. The only supported notifications are those that appear in Action Center, since those are toast notifications sent through the Windows platform.

Comment: Thanks! It appears that Microsoft Edge is also not using toast notifications. Am I correct? Any browser use the Windows 10 notification framework?

Comment: Edge will be using Win10 toast notifications. I don't believe Facebook has been updated to send notifications while running in Edge yet, but any Edge web notifications will certainly be using the Windows 10 notification framework.